# ubuntu software manager does not function properly

Tags: update-manager

My ubuntu software manager does nort function properly after i install update from the update manager? Why is that so? 
Is there any way to restore to default setting maybe?

Can i reset the system?

Answer (score 0):

Go on terminal and type in;

sudo apt-get -f install

that should refresh everything and make things work fine, that's what i did when the same thing happened to me, i don't know if it will work or not though..